# Change View of Active ExpressJS Route -- Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, express, url-routing

I have an active express route -- already has been defined with a template.

```
app.get('/route', function route(req, res) {
   db.get('db_ID', function compileAndRender(err, doc) {
      var stream = mu.compileAndRender('theme-file.extension', doc)
      stream.pipe(res)
   })
```

})

Now, I want to be able to change the view file for that route later on in the application. How would I do this?

Basically, how to I tell express that '/route' should have a new 'theme-file.extension'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I just had to figure out another way of thinking of the issue. Instead of setting each route manually, I used a parameter variable to do it dynamically.

The code looks like this:

```
//Set up dynamic routes for all pages
app.get('/:page_name', function(req, res) {

    db.get('pages_routes', function(err, doc) {
        var pure_routes = doc.pure_routes,
             requested_page = req.params.page_name, 
            page_info = _.findWhere(pure_routes, { "url" : requested_page })

        if (page_info !== undefined) {
            db.get(page_info.id, function compileAndRender(err, doc) {
                var stream = mu.compileAndRender(page_info.theme, doc)
                stream.pipe(res)
            })
        } else {
            res.redirect('/index.html')
        }
    })
})
```

This made the code a lot more concise and easier to work with, in my opinion. If you're interested in seeing the code more in action, you can look at the project [here](https://github.com/maned/goblin) (and contribute if you see something that can be improved!). Hope this helps someone else out there!